# getResourceAsStream() works on Windows but not on Linux

Tags: java, maven, classloader

I have a following class in my project:

```
package com.test.schedule.payloads;

import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * Loads payload from file
 */
public class FilePayload{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(FilePayload.class);
    private final String filename;

    public FilePayload(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public String getAsString() {
        try {
            return IOUtils.toString(new InputStreamReader(FilePayload.class.getResourceAsStream(filename), Charsets.UTF_8));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error while loading file: '" + filename +'\'', e);
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

In resources directory of my project (maven one) I have file in following path:

```
com/test/schedule/payloads/schedule-payload.xml
```

When I execute getAsString() with filename equal to "schedule-payload.xml" on Windows everything works fine. But when the same code is executed on Linux server it returns null on getResourceAsStream(). I have no idea how to fix it so code works both on Windows and Linux. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Verify that the jar file actually contains the file in question.

Comment: What is the value of filename you are passing? change your call to FilePayload.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName)  and fileName should not be absolute path. It should be relative to classpath like /relativepat_to_filename

Comment: The value of fileName is equal to "schedule-payload.xml".

Comment: FilePayload.class..getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/schedule-payload.xml") - try this

Comment: This doesn't work even on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check, that everything on your path to this file "com/test/schedule/payloads/schedule-payload.xml" is lowercase, as linux paths are case sensitive and windows paths are not case sensitive.

Comment: The name of the file was build dynamically and it turned out to be built uppercase. I'm really suprised that on Windows it was treated as the same file as if it was lowercase.